# AWSEducate account - Access key and secret key keep changing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The Access keys shown on Vocareum when using an AWSEducate account keep changing from time to time. How am I supposed to access S3 services from a backend service I'm writing? Is this not supported by the AWSEducate program?